# Php unable to create user

Tags: php, rest, api, raspberry-pi

I'm new to create REST API on my Raspberry. I installed in it MySql and I want to create the signup api. I found a tutorial on the web and I followed it. I'm having some issue by create user in my table by using the API I wrote. Here's the structure of my `user_usr` table:

[image]

I create a PHP class to connect to the DB like so:

```
<?php
class Database {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "my_db_name";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "my_password";
    public $conn;
    function getConnection() {
        $this->conn = null;
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch(PDOException $exception) {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Then I create the `user.php` class like so:

```
<?php
class User {
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "user_usr";
    public $id_usr;
    public $name_usr;
    public $surname_usr;
    public $email_usr;
    public $password_usr;
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
    function create() {
        $query =  "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name_usr = :name,
                surname_usr = :surname,
                email_usr = :email,
                password_usr = :password";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $this->name_usr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name_usr));
        $this->surname_usr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->surname_usr));
        $this->email_usr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email_usr));
        $this->password_usr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password_usr));
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name_usr);
        $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $this->surname_usr);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email_usr);
        $password_hash = password_hash($this->password_usr, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

And I create the class to create user (`create_user.php`) like so:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/api3/");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once 'config/database.php';
include_once 'objects/user.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$user = new User($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$user->name_usr = $data->name;
$user->surname_usr = $data->surname;
$user->email_usr = $data->email;
$user->password_usr = $data->password;

if ($user->create()) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "User was created."));
} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to create user."));
}
?>
```

When I tri to run the API with Postman at this address: `http://my_raspberry_ip/api/create_user.php` I see that the query fails and I don't know why. In Postman I get an error 400:

[image]

It seems that the row `$stmt->execute()` in file `user.php` for some reason fails and it return false so the server shows me the 400 error.
Anyone has an idea why it fails? Can anyone help me to find a solution for this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: "Anyone has an idea why it fails?" You can use `$stmt->errorInfo()` to find out!

Comment: And you should definitely not do this: `$this->password_usr=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password_usr));`

Comment: Any formatting (e.g. `htmlspecialchars` and `strip_tags`) should be done on output, not input. That way you can change the formatting whenever you want. Sure, it works fine when you only output it to a web page, but what happens when you later decide you want to save the username in a plain text log file, or send it in a plain text email? Then you're going to be getting a bunch of HTML entities.

Comment: @ChrisWhite when I use `$stmt->errorInfo()` where I can see the output? I'm sorry if I'm asking this kind of question but it’s the first time I try to write an API... How it should be the correct API to create an user? Can you write it in an answer? Thank you!